# Not able to remove scroll bar from pop up window in shiny

Tags: html, css, shiny

I was able to increase the width of the pop up window using css, but I was not able to remove teh horizontal scroll bar . Please refer below

[image]

CSS code used below

```
tags$head(
            tags$style(".modal-dialog{ width:100%}")),tags$head(tags$style(".modalClass {overflow-x: hidden;}"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```r
tags$head(tags$style('.modal-dialog{ width:100%}  
                     .modal-open {overflow: hidden;}')
```